# SystemJS - moment is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, systemjs

I'm using `JSPM`, `AngularJS`, `TypeScript`, `SystemJS` and `ES6` and my project is running pretty well... unless I try to use momentJS.

This is the error I get:

> TypeError: moment is not a function

This is part of the code:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

More:

```
var momentInstance = moment(value);
```

If I debug it, moment is an object not a function:

[image]

This is what my moment.js JSPM package looks like:

```
module.exports = require("npm:moment@2.11.0/moment.js");
```

I've read a lot and couldn't find a way to solve this... any ideas?

Some things I've read/tried:

[How to use momentjs in TypeScript with SystemJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938561/how-to-use-momentjs-in-typescript-with-systemjs)

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/154

https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-datepicker/issues/5

[Typescript module systems on momentJS behaving strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987273/typescript-module-systems-on-momentjs-behaving-strangely)

https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/issues/153

Thanks!

Comment: who did you do your injection dependency of moment in angular ?

Comment: @AlainIb hi, thanks for your comment. I'm sorry, but do you mean why? If so, what would you recommend as an alternative? Thanks again.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Simply remove the grouping (`* as`) from your import statement:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

Without digging too deeply in to the [source code](https://github.com/moment/moment/), it looks like `moment` usually exports a function, that has all kinds of methods and other properties attached to it.

By using `* as`, you're effectively grabbing all those properties and attaching them to a *new* object, destroying the original function. Instead, you just want the chief export (`export default` in ES6, `module.exports` object in Node.js).

Alternatively, you could do

```
import moment, * as moments from 'moment';
```

to get the moment function *as* `moment`, and all the other properties on an object called `moments`. This makes a little less sense when converting ES5 exports like this to ES6 style, because `moment` will retain the same properties.

Comment: @eestein Cheers. Here's the MDN article on [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import). In my opinion, it's a little too brief right now, but it does cover most of the syntax.

Comment: I too had tried `import * as moment from 'moment'` which gave me the "moment is not a function" error.  Changing it as you suggested to `import moment from 'moment'` just changes the error to `moment_1.default is not a function`.  what is going on here? (It seems that changing the way I import has caused typescript to compile my `moment()` function call into a `moment_1.default`  function call.)

Comment: I had to add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` under *compilerOptions* in *tsconfig.json* file

Comment: I came here when get runtime error `moment_1.default is not a function`. Then I changed `import moment from 'moment';` => `import * as moment from 'moment';` and this worked.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
import moment from 'moment/src/moment'
```

Answer (score 0):

A beginner JS mistake that was giving me the same error:

```
foobar(moment) {
  console.log(moment().whatever());
}
```

Naming a parameter `moment` breaks access to the `moment()` function.

Answer (score 0):

AS plot in the official documentation [momentJs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/node-js/) my problems were solved via nodeJS approach:

```
var moment = require('moment');
moment(); //this does not emit the errors
```

Answer (score 0):

To get moment work as a function, if you are using ES6 and babel, you must import it in this way:

```
import moment from 'moment'
```

and not, as written in the documentation

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
import * as moment from "moment";
```

add this instead

```
import moment from "moment";
```

And that is how it is used in your context

```
{moment(finalOrder.order.order.order.dateOrdered).format("MM-DD-YYYY")}
```